# How to mark not to call super class' implementation when overriding?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose a Library's method takes a callback handler `Handler`, but for handling the result, the same logic is used over and over again. So, I created a class `SimpleHandler` that has the logic. The users that use that class are suppose to override its methods `onSuccess` `onFail`, if necessary. But if the handling is not necessary for the specific case, the user may not override them, and the `SimpleHandler`'s default handler will be used.

The problem is that when I auto-complete the methods, the IDE automatically inserts super calls, like `super.onFail()`. For this code, as you see below, if it is overridden, the super method should not be called. Is there any way to mark that the super method should not be called when overridden, so the IDE will stop inserting it?

```
interface Handler
{
    fun onFinished(result:Int);
}

abstract class SimpleHandler:Handler
{
    override fun onFinished(result: Int)
    {
        if(result==0)
        {
            onSuccess();
        }
        else
        {
            onFail();
        }
    }

    open fun onSuccess()
    {
        println("The developer is so lazy that he did not do anything.");
    }
    open fun onFail()
    {
        println("The developer is so lazy that he did not do anything.");
    }
}

fun doSomething(handler:Handler)
{
    handler.onFinished(10);
}

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{

    doSomething(object: SimpleHandler(){
        override fun onSuccess() {
            println("I won! I won!");
        }

        override fun onFail() {
            //super.onFail();
            println("Me fail English?");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this is an IDE specific question, in my experience if you use an IDE like Android Studio it does not generate `super.<method name>` but a `TODO("not implemented")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IDEA/Android Studio, this is governed by [`Editor > File and Code Templates`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html) under `Settings`.

On my installation, I see `Overridden Method Body` and `Overridden Scala Method Body` but no special template for Kotlin. So I would expect Kotlin to be using the Java template.

You can change this template not to call `super` for a given method name, but it looks like you don't have access to the supertype's name. See the linked documentation for how templates can be shared.

Comment: For most other classes, calling the super.XXX() may be necessary. In some cases, I think Android Studio warned me for not calling that super method. But I wanted to know if there is a way to tell the user/IDE that calling super.XXX() is not necessary.

Comment: That's why I said "for a given method name". It's an Apache Velocity template, you have conditionals. There is a problem if you also have other methods with same name, but you can choose the names to avoid it.

Comment: This approach has major limitations, I just don't think there's anything better (at least currently).

Comment: If there is no better way, I will take this as the answer. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no problem in writing something like this:

```
fun doSomething(handler:Handler, result: Int) {
    handler.onFinished(result)
}
    fun main() {
        doSomething(object: SimpleHandler() {
            override fun onFail() {
                println("My custom message")
            }
        }, 10)
    }

    fun main2() {
        doSomething(object : SimpleHandler() {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                println("My other custom message")
            }
        }, 0)
    }
```

The developer only needs to override, if needed, the callback he's interested in.
In this case, in main() fails, it'll print "my custom message". If it succeeds, the default onSuccess() will be called.
The reverse is also true for main2(): If it succeeds, it'll print "My other custom message", but it it fails, it'll simply call the default onSuccess.

Tested on AS 3.1.1 with org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.31

Comment: I know that works, but my point was to know if there is any mechanical way to let the users (and the IDE) know that they need not call the super.onFail method when they overwrite it, other than saying so in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand then. Calling super would be up to them, if they want to extend the base behavior that you'd have implemented or not.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define a separate lint detector for that.
Lint highlights overrides which should call super, but don't, by use of `@CallSuper` annotation, which is what this Lint detector enables:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:tools/base/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/CallSuperDetector.java

Granted that might be something new to learn first, but writing custom Lint rules is not that hard. These are some good starting points:

Android Lint Tool Guide https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html

2017 Kotlin Conference Lint Talk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8yX5-lPS6o